# Multiple buttons. Passing actions to the next button in Java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Java Android question

I have x, say 5, buttons in a row. 
Each button has a different number value displayed on the button.
Button one is active, the rest are not- not clickable. They are greyed out.
To show Button 1 is active it fades up and down.
Once clicked the button pops up a message. The user Ok's that, this activates Button 2, and deactivates Button 1.
Then it happens through all buttons, one by one. The final button doesn't produce the pop up message.

My question...
I want to create a method that sets the first button as current and then once clicked sets the next as current, and so on.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I don't need to know how to fade buttons etc, its literally how to set button as current, and within that method the user click sets the next button as current.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT
OK, I've had a go...its not working, but it seems so close...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_one);

    int[] buttonIds = new int[]   {R.id.button_1,R.id.button_2,R.id.button_3,R.id.button_4,R.id.button_5};
    setButton(buttonIds);
}



private void setButton(int[] buttId){

    int isCurrent = 0;
    while(isCurrent < 5) {

        Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(buttId[isCurrent]);
        //TODO Make current button pulse

        currentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                v.clearAnimation();
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                v.setFocusable(false);
                v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                v.setClickable(false);
                setTimer();
                isCurrent++;
            }
        });
```

I know that the problem is the isCurrent++ is not accessible outside the onClick method. How do I right this? Am I close or is this a major funk up and do I have to rethink?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: My suggestion is: Store your buttons on a list, and on OK click passe the clicked button index to the method (lets say *switchButtonState()* ) and do the rest of work. In this method you have the list of buttons, index of clicked button(so you can disable it) and you can get the next button from the list by index+1 (to enable it)

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet...I cant get my head around the passing of the token from button to next, based on user click. Once I have that worked out, I know how to change the state of it etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global variable which track the current button, and check this variable to identify the current active button for determining the action in onClickListener. To fade out a button try this code snippet

```
button.setClickable(false);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need something like this:

```
private int activeButton = 1;

private void buttonClickHandler(){
    switch(activeButton++){
        case : 1
           button1.setEnabled(true):
           // show popup, hide/animate for button 1
          break;
        case : 2 
           button2.setEnabled(true);
           // same for button 2
        case : 3
           // same for button 3
        case : 4 
           // same for button 4
 }
```

Comment: What if there are 200 buttons in ListView?

Comment: There are only 5 and he doesn't mention a ListView so this approach is fine. If he has 200 buttons in a listview he should write an adapter and apply the viewholder pattern

Comment: Read his description again, this time more carefully. He mentions 5 just as an example: `I have x, say 5, buttons in a row`

Comment: If he click and close the dialog/popup (not select "OK" option) "*activeButton*" will be incremented and on the next click you'll have a wrong value of "*activeButton*".

Comment: @Marius I did, I interpret this as it might be 3, it might be 10, not a very big amount ;)

Comment: Anyway, no matter the amount, your code, as it is now, would fail very very horribly.

Comment: @Rami Dismissing the dialog might be handled by implementing a listener which lowers the value of activeButton when the dialog is dismissed or, likewise, only increases its value when the OK button is pressed

Comment: Yep! but it's a bit complicated approach, and you haven't mentioned that in your answer.